# What is the difference betwee "nuget install" , "Install-Package" and "choco install"?

Tags: windows, powershell, nuget, chocolatey

And more specific questions. Do I understand right that:

1. "nuget install" installs always to the directory you run it from?
2. "choco install" installs to special choco's directory and than runs the scripts to spread it in the system?
3. "nuget install" is just a wrapper for the Install-Package?

Comment: Where is the "Install-Package" from your question's title?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question. 
This is PowerShell command. I can't understand the difference between that and nuget install.

Comment: Your points 1. and 3. both say "nuget install".

Comment: 3rd has Install-Package also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NuGet is a packaging framework that provides packaging for NuGet, PowerShell Modules (PowerShell Gallery), and Chocolatey.

PackageManagement (aka OneGet) is a Package Manager ***Manager*** (yes, really) that implements `Install-Package` to work with package managers (called providers) like NuGet, PowerShell Get, and Chocolatey.

- NuGet (the tool, not the framework) is used for development purposes and typically packages software libraries (dlls).
- Chocolatey is for Software Deployment and Management and typically packages software, tools, and applications.
- `Install-Package` is an interface to either of those (and more) through providers.

**NOTE:** If you want to interface with Chocolatey in PackageManagement (through `Install-Package`), use ChocolateyGet for now and wait until the official provider `Chocolatey` is available. The current is a prototype. If you want more details, please see https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-oneget/issues/5#issuecomment-275404099.

Comment: Awesome answer. Exactly I was searching for! Thank you!

Comment: But one more question: so nuget.exe and choco utilities relay upon different sources, not listed in PackageManager?

Comment: No idea if those sources are listed in PackageManager - I know the prototype Chocolatey provider didn't have this functionality (choco.exe does). With ChocolateyGet, you manage default sources with choco.exe (`choco source -?`). I can't speak for NuGet but I'd assume the provider would use same source that nuget.exe does when not explicitly specified.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Install-package may act as a wrapper for nuget (basically), but there can be other package providers (and there are), so it can not only call nuget.

```
C:\> get-packageprovider

Name                     Version
----                     -------
msi                      3.0.0.0
msu                      3.0.0.0
NuGet                    2.8.5.207
PowerShellGet            1.0.0.1
Programs                 3.0.0.0
```

Choco is just another package provider. you could use it standalone or using the install-package. you can install choco with something like `install-packageprovider chocolatey`

Comment: Thank you. Main focal point of the question: what the difference between them.

Comment: well, those are different things (to some extent). nuget\choco\etc are package management providers. there's no real difference between them (in the sense of what they try to achieve, they just do it slightly differently). I'm not sure what do you expect to hear as an answer. its pretty clear there's no real difference between them. its like asking whats the difference between a kia and toyota. no difference. they get you from point a to point b.

Comment: I am sure there is. Otherwise people wouldn't say "nuget for dependencies, choco for apps installation". And who will invent something new if old already solves same problems?

Comment: oh lol, yeah. https://xkcd.com/927/ I'm not saying they are exactly the same, but they are mostly the same.

Comment: Will be interesting for you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662550/difference-between-chocolatey-and-nuget

Comment: @4c74356b41 There is quite a difference in functionality, so maybe it's more like comparing a Kia Optima to a Tesla Model S. They both are package managers, but Chocolatey does a lot more than just get the files. Chocolatey uses the NuGet framework for just one aspect of what it does.